# Loop and calculate average in Stata

Tags: loops, average, stata

I am trying to calculate the Gini coefficient as the average over five repetitions. My code doesn't correctly work, and I cannot find a way to do it.

`inequal7` is a user-written command.

```
gen gini=.
forval i=1/5 {
    mi xeq `i' : inequal7 income [aw=hw0010]
    gen gini_`i'=.
    scalar gini_`i'  = r(gini)
    replace gini_`i'= r(gini)
    if `i' ==5 {
        replace gini = sum(gini_1+gini_2+gini_3+gini_4+gini_5)/5
    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you please explain what is right and wrong with this? We don't know your goal/what the "gini coeffiecient..." means.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to ask questions. As @Avery tactfully implies "My code is wrong" is not informative in itself.

Comment: A pointless edit changed "My code is wrong" to what you can read now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no context on or example of the dataset you're using. This may not work but it's likely to be closer to legal and correct than what you have.

```
scalar gini = 0 
forval i=1/5 {
    mi xeq `i' : inequal7 income [aw=hw0010]
    scalar gini  = scalar(gini) + r(gini)
}
scalar gini = scalar(gini) / 5
```

Notes:

1. Using variables to hold constants is legal, but not necessarily good style.
2. `sum()` gives the running or cumulative sum; applied to a variable that's a constant it does far more work than you need,  and at best the correct answer will just be that in observation 1. As you're feeding it the sum of 5 values, it's redundant any way.
3. Watch out: names for scalars and variables occupy the same namespace.

If this is a long way off what you want, and you get no better answer, you're likely to need to give much more detail.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I have survey data which are multiply imputed - five times. There is no official solution that I know of in Stata for Gini coefficients under multiple imputation and weighted data. I can account for weighted data using mi xeq: [aw=weight] but no for multiply imputed data. So, my idea is that once I have the Gini coefficient for one implicate, I can repeat this calculation for the other 4 implicates. By averaging them I will get the multiple imputation estimate of the Gini coefficient. I tried the code provided but I got an error: type mismatch r(109);

Comment: I've tested the code to do with scalars independently, so the problem is, I guess,  with your call to `inequal7` or some other part of the code you're not showing us. Check for string variables that should be numeric. I've never used `mi xeq`.  As already commented, the question is a long way short of an MCVE.

Comment: Yes, indeed. The problem was with inequal7. I tried a different user-written command and it works. Thanks.